# Start Robotium Test Case from another Activity

Tags: android, robotium

I want to create a test harness on an Android, which is effectively a service listening to certain broadcasts and starting robotium tests automatically.

Once the service receives a specific broadcast, it will fire a robotium test case.

However I can't see to find a way to start a Robotium test case from an Activity, Service or BroadcastListener. I always get the issue of NoClassDefFounderror.

My individual Robotium test cases work fine in isolation. I just need a way to 'fire' them from a parent application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the [startInstrumentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startInstrumentation%28android.content.ComponentName,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle%29) command.